# How to display *block number* instead *date value* on Wordpress posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, customization, custom-field, date

Ideally, the goal is to show the block number (ie: 782667) instead of the date value (ie: 26 March 2023 4:44PM CT) on all wordpress posts and pages that currently display it.

There's maybe a script we can add to the `functions.php` in the wordpress child-theme currently in user?

Comment: What is a block number?

Comment: do you mean post ID? There's no such thing as "block number", if it's not the posts ID you're going to have to be more specific about what it is and where it comes from

Comment: Thanks for your responses. The `blockNumber` is the sequential number of a block mined in the bitcoin blockchain, every block is mined in a specific time, one every 10-15 min circa. For example, [block number 783184 was mined on 2023-03-30 07:02](https://mempool.space/block/000000000000000000003605972c1db546165cbce97197dcc7a7e72e54ccf3a3). 

Ideally the function will read the post/page date and convert it at blockNumber. Not sure is clear but please let me know if you have any further questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up building **Bitcoin Block Date Converter**, a plugin for WordPress and compatible with the majority of themes using this for

```
$ date -ud "1/1/2017"
Sun Jan 1 00:00:00 UTC 2017
$ date -ud "1/1/2017" +%s
1483228800
```

+add three zeroes to that number and append it to a blockchain.com URL:

`https://www.blockchain.com/btc/blocks/1483228800000`

And there you have it the block number:

`446033 (Main Chain) 2017-01-01 00:02:33`

**For more info:**

**Repo** on [GitHub](https://github.com/SuperAtic-LABS/Bitcoin-Block-Date-Converter)

**Demo** web [site](https://veintiuno.world/m/digitales/bitcoin-block-date-converter-wordpress-plugin/)

**Donate** on [Geyser](https://geyser.fund/project/bitcoinpriceconverterwordpressplugin)

.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea what a 'block number' is, but when themes output the date for a post they will use either [`the_date()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_date/) or [`the_time()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_time/) (or both). You can replace the output using the filters [`the_date()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_date/) or [`the_time()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_time/):

```
add_filter(
    'the_date',
    function( $the_date, $format ) {
        $block_number = 'whatever a block number is';
        
        return $block_number;
    },
    10,
    2
);
```

Comment: Please see response on comment [id="comment-606263"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/414952/how-to-display-block-number-instead-date-value-on-wordpress-posts#comment-606263) above 

Comment: Ok well in that case getting the actual block number doesn’t have anything to do with WordPress. You’d just need to add whatever code is required to get that number and use it in the code from this answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your contribution, we're trying now to [understand what API source to use](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/117751/theres-any-open-api-to-gather-the-blocknumber-data) and how to [write the request into the function.php](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/117706/how-to-display-block-number-instead-date-value-on-wordpress-posts)

Comment: Those questions are asking in the context of WordPress, which is not relevant. You want to know how to get the number in _PHP_. Ask that and you’re more likely to get good answers. Once you have that you can plug it into the code I’ve given here.